# How to implement Kafka like distribution in RabbitMQ?

Tags: apache-kafka, rabbitmq

I have a chat-bot webhook handler which will just publish the event to the queue. I want multiple consumers to handle these events, but events with the same Id should be handled by the same consumer to ensure in order handling for particular user. It can be easily achieved with Kafka partitions. But I have no idea how to organise it in RabbitMQ. 
Any ideas?